# Modifying page content before rendering in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, helper

I want to use different currencies in pages according to user's preferences. Users can set their default currency to GBP, EUR or USD. But all the pages already are written with prices in GBP i.e. `'£'`.

I don't know how to approach with the problem. First I though to get the page content just before rendering with `preDispatch()` or something like it, modifying it and then render the modified View. I can get the View within the controller, but only like an object. Another problem is that I have offers written from the Control Panel too and they are not included to the View Object. When I `var_dump($view);` the View is an object but the offers from Control Panel are displayed in the screen just like normal HTML.

I didn't want to edit all the created pages. It will be very laborious. 
I looked at `Zend_Currency` helper too, but I think it couldn't help in that situation.
Any suggestions how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a filter to the view. [This article](http://matthewturland.com/2008/06/04/output-filters-in-zend_view/) by Matthew Turland explains the process and has an example.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595711/in-zend-framework-applications-what-purpose-does-the-views-filters-serve) which features an answer by Bill Karwin.

That said, the better way to do it is to probably use `Zend_Locale` to generate the correct output from the outset. But adding filters after the output is already created - but before it is sent to the client - sounds like a way to deal with your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you, David. I will try this kind of view filter tomorrow and will write the results. I think that the article by Matthew Turland will solve the problem.

Comment: The only problem is that I couldn't made the filter work. I don't know where to put it. Tried different places like in library, views/filter etc. but still getting a 500 Server Error. For example I try `$this->_helper->layout->getLayoutInstance()->getView()
                        ->addFilterPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/views/filters')
                        ->addFilter('Minify');` in `init()` and `class Minify
{
    public function filter($string)
    {
        return $string."TEST";
    }
}` for the filter.

Comment: I usually add the filter in `postDispatch()` plugin, but controller `init()` should be fine. I'd turn on errors and throwExceptions to see what the exact error is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this through post-processing. Instead, use a view-helper when outputting the currency to reflect the user's locale.

Comment: Hello, Mike. I wrote a helper for that. Is this a right way to resolve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366810/custom-view-helper-crashes-when-gets-a-string-parameter? The helper crashes for now but can it be a solution? The bad side is that I should edit all the pages in the application which be a little hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Posit: I would assume that if you are changing currency based on user preference, other content may change slightly as well. Essentially what you are allowing your user to do is tailor the Locale to their specifics.

> getTranslationList() gives you access to localized information of several types. These information are useful if you want to display localized data to a customer without the need of translating it. They are already available for your usage.

The folowing code will give you tons (seriously check the link at the bottom of this post) of locale settings you can use:

```
$list = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('language', 'de_AT');
print_r ($list);
```

Most importantly, some of the values you can get:

- CurrencySymbol
- NameToCurrency
- CurrencyToName
- CurrencyRounding
- CurrencyFraction
- CurrencyToRegion
- RegionToCurrency

reference: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.locale.functions.html#zend.locale.getdata

Comment: Thank you for `getTranslationList()`, Francis. But with it I should edit all the existing pages in the application, am I right?

Comment: Let me preface this by saying, I've never used Locale info in any of my apps. But, how I would set this up is by calling getTranslationList() with the user's locale info `('language', 'USERS_SETTING')` in your Bootstrap.php file (predispatch + after session is loaded) save the values as constants OR use Zend_Registry. Everywhere in your app where you want to use these values, call from the registry or use the constant

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the internals of the Zend Framework, but you should be able to just use an output buffer and override whatever function actually renders the result, then `str_replace` over the contents of the buffer. Probably not a particularly elegant solution though.

Comment: This was my first idea, but as I say I couldn't get the plain html before View is rendered. I can get only the View Object and offers from Control Panel (backend) are not inside it, there are only these from the frontend.